# python pip3 cannot install zoneinfo on Linux Debian

Tags: python, linux, pip

How can `zoneinfo` be installed on a Linux Debian 10 machine? our script is working just fine on Mac. When pushed to Linux Debian and run, the script returns the error:

```
myemail@repo-name:~/path-to/mainfolder$ python3 main_cbb_v2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_cbb_v2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils import *
  File "/home/pathto-utils/utils.py", line 16, in <module>
    from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoneinfo'
```

and when we attempt to install the library, we get the error:

```
pip3 install zoneinfo
Collecting zoneinfo
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple
/zoneinfo/
```

and we get this same exact error even if `sudo su` is run beforehand. And if `backports` prefix is used:

```
pip3 install backports.zoneinfo
Requirement already satisfied: backports.zoneinfo in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.2.1)
```

How can this be troubleshooted further?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`zoneinfo` is [new in python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), so the undelying issue is probably that you have different python versions on different systems. You can either upgrade your python version or you use the `backports` module which you already have installed, but then your code needs to be:

```
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
```

Comment: ahh makes sense, thank you very much

Comment: and our server has python 3.7 so this did seem to be the issue